# How do I make a "text" from textview(with a transparent background) set by setContentView( ) be displayed above my layout in activity.xml?

Tags: java, android

```java
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.countdown_main);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Get the message from intent
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setTextSize(45);
    textView1.setText(message);
    setContentView(R.layout.countdown_main);

    // Set the text view as an activity layout
    setContentView(textView1);


}
```

Why is it that my view from countdown_main.xml isn't being shown directly underneath the setcontentview() ?

I would like the text in textview1 to be shown in the middle of my activity screen on top of my layout in countdown_main.xml .

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

SetContentView sets the entire view for your app.  It replaces the previous view.  If you want to add a view to the screen, the best way would be to put that view in your xml.  If you really wanted to add it dynamically, you'd find a ViewGroup (like a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout) in your xml via findViewById.  Then you would add the new view to it as a child view. Make sure to set its layout parameters as well.

Comment: Could you explain to me how I could do this, I do not understand how I can parse the info from the xml to the java code. Thanks.